# Is it dangerous to expose user id?

Tags: php, mysql, database, security

In my web app, I'm using user id as login **SESSION** and to view profile.

```
Let say
John's ID is 1
James's ID is 2
```

And if you want to view the profile of John, it will pass on the URL like this

```
http://website.com/view-profile?uid=1
```

You can able to view if you are registered user.

Are there any vulnerabilities on the **SESSION** and the user?

Safety recommendations are welcome.

Comment: If you click to see your own SO user profile, you will see that your user id is exposed here as well. Conclusion: simply exposing the id is not a problem. But we can't possibly know if your code is vulnerable to any attack.

Comment: Depending on how you do stuff, it could be dangerous, yes. But it really shouldn’t be, so if it is, fix your system.

Comment: Using non-parameterized queries is a more common and more dangerous problem.

Comment: It could be dangerous. but depend on how you code them.

Comment: Thanks =) In my search profile page, I'm also using a username to query the database. Is that safe?

Comment: Related: [Should I obscure database primary keys (IDs) in application front end?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/56357)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it dangerous to expose user id?

No.

> if there's a vulnerability on the SESSION and the user?

It is unclear what you are asking but as long as you are getting the user id from the PHP *session* to authorize a user, it is safe.

Comment: In my search profile page, I'm also using a username to query the database. Is that safe?

Answer (score 0):

The session is stored on the server.  The only direct interaction the browser might have with it is a cookie containing the session id (or some other means if cookies are disabled).

If it makes you feel any better, the Symfony2 framework stores the entire User as a serialized object inside the session when a user is logged in, and security is in their mission statement.

There are also alternative ways to store a session, typically PHP stores them as temporary files, but they can also be stored against a database.  Essentially the session is safe from the public.

Regarding the User ID however, the User ID can't (or at least shouldn't) be enough information to provide authorization, only a username and password can do that, and after the session is created the system no longer needs to question the users authenticity, therefore doesn't require the password (or even the username depending on how you set it up).

Comment: @user3431424 well since many websites use an email address as a username and these email addresses are often public it should be ok, but you should probably enforce a strong password policy, which should be the case regardless.